# Check if Power BI Dataset tables were refreshed with new data

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a Power BI report that shows whether a specific Report/Dataset has been successfully refreshed or not.

In my case, it is about whether the tables composing the dataset have new data or not. It is possible that the refresh was successful but no new data was inserted.

Is there a way to obtain this information? Essentially, the final report would be a matrix with the names of the reports/datasets and then the status. For example, if it was green, it means new data was inserted; if there was no change in the data (countrows), then it would be red, etc. (similiar with below image)

[image]

Unfortunately I don't have premium licenses, as that would enable connecting to the XMLA endpoint and executing some DMVs to obtain this information.

Another possibility is to execute countrows in the source, and since I'm using Spark, I would use DESCRIBE HISTORY to obtain the differences in counts between the current and previous versions. However, in this case, the challenge would be the mapping with report names and tables, as I have many tables and reports, and manual mapping would be very time-consuming and bad in terms of management.

It might be possible to obtain the information using the Power BI API as well, but I'm not as familiar with that.

Therefore, if anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You'll need to query the power bi api, and get the data that way. It will give you access to the schedule history

Comment: @Jon I trying to check this GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes but it only offers the start_time, end_time and status. But I can obtain the difference between the start_time and end_date, and if it's small, it might indicate that I'm not refreshing new data. I'll continue to investigating

Comment: yes that can be very interesting, probably I'll use pyspark to get that value and store it. But do you know where I can find any information about this api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets{dataset_id}/rowsCount ?I tried searching in Microsoft's documentation, but I couldn't find any information or a sample response